# Response.Redirect() Works in Visual Studio but not IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm trying to upload a basic web application from visual studio on Windows 7 to an IIS environment on Windows Server 2007.

Though launching it from IIS displays the Login page, trying to navigate past it to the main menu returns this error:

```
Server Error in Application "PARKING/PARKING ASSIGNMENTS WEB"Internet Information Services 7.0
Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Detailed Error Information
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL http://localhost:81/Parking Assignments Web/Home 
Physical Path C:\ParkingAssignmentsWeb\Home 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous 
 Most likely causes:
•The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
•The URL contains a typographical error.
•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
 Things you can try:
•Create the content on the Web server.
•Review the browser URL.
•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here. 
 Links and More InformationThis error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again. 
View more information »
```

This is the code I used for navigation:

```
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

Why would this navigation work on Visual Studio but not on IIS?

UPDATE: I tried the variations of the Redirect command you guys showed me but all of them gave a 404 error, which leads me to believe that the problem isn't with the command but with something else. Any idea what?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Parking Assignments Web/Home.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("~/Parking Assignments Web/Home");
```

Answer (score 0):

It treats `Home.aspx` as a relative path.

Use it like:

```
Response.Redirect("/Home.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

when you deploy to IIS a different web server is being used. Visual studio uses a web server with limited options and in most cases but not all an application should run without changes when deployed to IIS on windows server.

Things to check

- Verify that the folder structure on your workstation looks the same as the folder structure deployed to the server.
- check permissions on the folders accessed by IIS on the web server
- Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); assumes that the file is in the same directory as the page that is invoking the transfer
- add a more complete path either ("/home.aspx") or ("/folder/home.aspx") where folder is the actual folder name that contains the .aspx file